# Как получить пересечение нескольких множеств?

Tags: python

У меня есть массив, который содержит множества (set). Мне нужно получить их пересечение. Как это сделать?
Пробовал так:

```
l = [set([1,2,3]), set([2,3,4]), set([3,4,5])]
list(map(&, l))
```

Не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если автору вопроса хочется именно функционального программирования, то можно так :)

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import __and__

l = [set([1,2,3]), set([2,3,4]), set([3,4,5])]

list(reduce(__and__, l))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
l = [set([1,2,3]), set([2,3,4]), set([3,4,5])]

print(set.intersection(*l))

>>> {3}
```

"*" оператор - это оператор распаковки коллекции.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

print(*l)

a b c d e f
```

Суть оператора в том, что массив l превратился в 6 различных значений (был 1 список - стало 6 элементов без списка).

Ну а [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set.intersection) - метод из стандатртной библиотеки.